# Can I generate a spend-proof with a cold-wallet?

Tags: cold-storage

I am trying to create a spend-proof on a cold-wallet (an air-gapped laptop), but thought that the wallet might need a connection to a node to create it.

**Is it possible to exchange data between a view-only wallet and a cold wallet, such that the latter can get all the information it needs to create a spend-proof?**

I am aware that the cold-wallet can create key-images for a view-only wallet if the latter provides the former with the needed outputs and was wondering whether something similar can be done for spend-proofs, or if that is a feature *exclusive* to a hot full wallet (i.e. exclusive to a wallet having the spend-key *and* which is connected to a node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove you have spent anything until you broadcast a transaction. So you'll do this on your hot wallet, when you broadcast the transaction. See [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1861/7493) for how to prove a payment.

For performing a cold and hot wallet tx, see [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2916/7493), and do the `get_tx_key txid` after step 11.

Comment: Does that mean that the `get_spend_proof` command relies on the transaction key too and thus can only be executed by a wallet that has broadcast the transaction?

Comment: `get_spend_proof` is slightly different and cannot be done on a watch-only wallet. To use that on a cold-wallet, you'd have to continue from step 11 to do 12, 1, 2 and 3 before calling `get_spend_proof`. But it requires a connection to a daemon, so my answer above is probably what you are looking for instead.

Comment: Nah I actually had the `get_spend_proof` command in mind but I didn't realize that "spend-proof" was ambiguous (in light of there also being `get_tx_key` for proving spends). Your answers did solve my problem regardless though, so thanks for the clarification, much appreciated! :)

Comment: Glad I could help.