# Sent some monero with the cli using the transfer command. How can I get the key to view proof that I sent it using an monero explorer?

Tags: block-explorer, key-image

I did a transfer using the cli and now I want to view it in the https://xmrchain.net explorer. What do I need from me to decode the outputs so I can prove that I sent it? And what commands do I need in the cli to output these things to decode the transaction on the explorer page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prove that a payment has been sent to a particular address?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1860/how-do-i-prove-that-a-payment-has-been-sent-to-a-particular-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the txid for your transaction:

> get_tx_key TXID

And replace TXID with that transaction's txid.

Note that once you disclose that secret tx key to a third party, that third party can use it in the same way you do (ie, to try to prove they sent that tx).